# Unexpected infinite loop after input reading

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that keeps asking a question until the user presses enter. But for some reason, the program goes into an infinite loop that continuously outputs:

"Enter the operation: You need to add '[' at the beginning of the set."

If you accidentally do not follow the rules. Now, the program should print that message but only once. I think the loop continuously asks for the operation but it goes straight to the error (If you do not enter anything, I guess that counts as not using an [ at the beginning).

I already know how to solve it but because I tried everything!! I am not sure how my solution changes anything... Can you give me advice on how to solve it and/or explain to me what is it about the do-while loop implemented at the end that does the trick?

Edit: TextIO is a class written by Eck, D. J. in his book. I will link the chapter where it gives the code here: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c2/s6.html

The problematic code is

```
 while (true) {
           System.out.print("\nEnter the operation: ");
           TextIO.skipBlanks();
           if (TextIO.peek() == '\n') { //There is no operation, end the program.
               break;
           }
           try {
               calculation(); 
           }
           catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
               
           }
}
```

The solution I implemented looks like this:

```
while (true) {
           System.out.print("\nEnter the operation: ");
           TextIO.skipBlanks();
           if (TextIO.peek() == '\n') { //There is no operation, end the program.
               break;
           }
           try {
               calculation(); 
           }
           catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
               
           }
           do {
               ch = TextIO.getAnyChar(); // Read ahead the "enter". 
               
           } while (ch != '\n'); //If necessary, make sure to stop the error message and keep the loop going.
       }
```

Thanks, guys!!

Comment: What is `TextIO`?

Comment: It is a class that was written by the author of the book I am using, it works usually like the Scanner Class but sometimes it is more simple. I just got used to using it.

Comment: Pls add the error trace, and TextIO class.

Comment: This is why I think all [mre]'s must include both the import statements and the main method.

Comment: @Amessihel you did answer the question, thank you! I will add it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using [**`TextIO`**](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/chapter2/textio/TextIO.java) class from David J. Eck's *[Introduction to Programming Using Java, Eighth Edition](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/index.html)* book.

According to the [source](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/chapter2/textio/TextIO.java) of the class:

> [`TextIO.peek()`] returns the next character in the current input source, **without actually removing** that character from the input.

You're checking the input actually without removing it. That's why in the next iteration, the loop keeps reading the same bad input, and throwing the exception indefinitely.

Also your fix performs what is lacking after calling `peek()`. Removing the char from the input.

Hence, replacing `peek()` by `getAnyChar()` in your first attempt solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's TextIO, you should use the standard [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Comment: It is a class that was given and written by the author of the book I am using. It works the same, but some methods are easier to implement. I just got used to them! Can you tell me why the do-while loop makes the difference? If I delete it, the program crashes because of an infinite loop and I tried so many different approaches but they do not work.

Comment: It's about the TextIO class, which I am not familiar with, I really suggest you use the conventional Scanner class.